# Don't we get a "2019: a year in moderation" post?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

Shog9 has been posting posted titled "2019: a year in moderation" in all the meta sites (e.g.: [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392550/2422776)'s, [MSU](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13925/304000)'s) with some interesting stats about how the main site is (self-)moderated.

We seem to have [had one last year](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/q/816/327). Don't we get one this year? Is it because it's a beta site, or just an oversight? (bad pun not intended).

Comment: Be patient... I may have started drinking before the script finished its run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do: [2019: a year in moderation](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/847/2019-a-year-in-moderation)